# Changing boxplot Fonts in R

Tags: r, fonts, boxplot

I am trying to change boxplot font to "Times New Roman" through this command in R:

```
library(extrafont)
loadfonts(device="win")
fonts()
boxplot(sp ~ grp, data = mydata,family="Times New Roman")
```

But the fonts in the plot does not change. How to I change all the text in boxplot graph?
Thanks in advance
[You can see the results here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCC4P.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
windowsFonts(
  A=windowsFont("Arial Black"),
  B=windowsFont("Bookman Old Style"),
  C=windowsFont("Comic Sans MS"),
  D=windowsFont("Times New Roman")
)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for (f in LETTERS[1:4]) {
  par(family=f)
  boxplot(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris, main = "Title", font=2)  
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The font family cannot be changed by setting `family` in `boxplot()`. Instead, use `par(family = "Times New Roman")` to modify this graphical parameter before calling `boxplot()`.

A reproducible example follows:

```
boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays)
boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, family = "serif")
# -> 'family' has no effect here

par(family = "serif")
boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays)
# -> font has changed
```